# Is there a chart that shows the breakdown of the protocol versions in use?

Tags: live-data, nodecount

Modern clients broadcast the protocol version.

A snapshot of the data summarizing the numbers per-client occasionally will appear, but I'm wondering if this info is published periodically or is otherwise publicly available on-demand.